# Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h" (Teensy 3.6)

Tags: c++, arduino, teensy

I know that there are already similar questions out there, but the given advices didn't really help. I want to control a servo motor with my new Teensy 3.6. If I compile my sketch, there appears an error:

```
In file included from C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\servo_test\servo_test.ino:1:0:

C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src/Servo.h:75:2: error: #error "This library only supports boards with an AVR, SAM, SAMD, NRF52 or STM32F4 processor."

 #error "This library only supports boards with an AVR, SAM, SAMD, NRF52 or STM32F4 processor."

  ^

Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Servo
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\teensy\avr\libraries\Servo
Error compiling for board Teensy 3.6.
```

My code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
void setup() {
}
void loop() {
}
```

If I swap the board to Arduino UNO the compilation process works and there aren't any errors:

```
Sketch uses 888 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 46 bytes (2%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2002 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes
```

Thank you for your answers in advance

Comment: You seem to have manually installed a Servo library. Have you tried removing that?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659250/multiple-libraries-were-found-for-servo-h-teensy-3-6, the Teensy 3.6 has a Kinetis K66 microcontroller.  That's not compatible with "AVR, SAM, SAMD, NRF52 or STM32F4", right?

Comment: How can I manually remove them?

Comment: I think I removed them, but there is still an error:


In file included from C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\servo_test\servo_test.ino:1:0:

C:\Users\Lehrer\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Servo\src/Servo.h:75:2: error: #error "This library only supports boards with an AVR, SAM, SAMD, NRF52 or STM32F4 processor."

 #error "This library only supports boards with an AVR, SAM, SAMD, NRF52 or STM32F4 processor."

  ^

Error compiling for board Teensy 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

"You seem to have manually installed a Servo library. Have you tried removing that?"

worked for me. Thanks again!